# How to convert a CD/DVD to ISO using cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, filesystems, dvd, iso-image

Is it possible to convert a CD/DVD to an ISO file using cmd.exe and if so, how?

I can think of using `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=cdrom_image.iso` with Linux systems, but in Windows?

Comment: You can always download `dd` from GnuWin32 if you want.

Comment: If you don't want to install 3rd party software, [this PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/marnix/3944688) (link obtained from [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324075/create-iso-image-using-powershell-how-to-save-istream-to-file)) works fine for creating ISOs from folder(s). Should work with folders from a CD/DVD too. If the disc is bootable however then the boot code might not be copied. ...

Comment: ... Perhaps something in [Cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html) can help. Otherwise I'm sure there's a PowerShell solution for complete disc image creation. If you don't get an answer here maybe you'd like to ask about a PS-specific solution on SO (and link to the question here so we can find it easily too)?

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not have native tools to do this from the command line. As Mehrdad suggests, you could install the windows version of dd to do this, but if you're going to install software, you may be better of with something designed to do this (like ImgBurn), rather than a more general tool like dd.